# I downloaded ubuntu but I also had to download WinZip in order to complete the download?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, downloads

I downloaded Ubuntu and in order to complete the download I had to download WInZip. I am so confused on why I had to that and what I have to do.

I'm on windows.

Comment: What do you mean you "had to download WinZip"? For what purpose?

Comment: If you mean in order to open the file you downloaded from Ubuntu.com, you're not supposed to open that directly. You need to "burn" it to a USB stick or DVD: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and then reboot to it.

Comment: And what exactly did you download?

Comment: Without cd/dvd burning software installed, Windows thinks the .iso is a zip file. It is not a zip file, you do not extract the iso, you burn it to a CD or live usb. See the link Oli gave.

Comment: In order to continue to download Ubuntu it said I must download WinZip. I downloaded the Ubuntu server and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do all that. Just download ISO file from Ubuntu website and then also download Universal USB installer from here [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Then install it on the Pen drive you want to do so.[image: Set up]
[image: Istallation complete]

You will be able to see these windows when you run this program on windows like this.
For further queries go to [Install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)